# Can I deploy to Azure Cloud Services with a mac?

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-cloud-services

### Deploy with non-windows SDK?

The documentation is vague or non-existent for deploying to Azure's Cloud Services from a non-windows environment. I have the Azure SDK for node.js and the CLI but there are no commands for publishing or building the required packages.

This repo used to solve the problem, but hasn't been touched in several years and no longer seems to work: https://github.com/c9/azure-cmdlet-node

### Found Documentation

*or lack thereof*

None of this explicitly says you can't deploy outside of Windows, but nor does it say you can:

This document explains deploying and building the package via Powershell: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-app/

This explains how to do it with git and an Azure Website (not Cloud Service): http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/

And this article talks about the package and configuration that needs to be generated: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. I tried and tried and eventually gave up.

https://mediocre.com/forum/topics/one-does-not-simply-run-node-js-on-microsoft-azure

Comment: Thanks for that link. Wish the Microsoft documentation would include that information.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried cross platform command line interface

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/

Comment: I installed, authenticated, and looked at all the commands under `services`. You can add/remove certs, create (but not deploy) a service, or delete it. That's about it.